# In Lasso regression, why is the intercept equal to $\bar{Y}$ when we center the columns of $X$

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients, lasso

I am currently learning Lasso regression, and I am confused about a lecture slide that I am looking at: [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/datamining/lectures/17-modr2.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/datamining/lectures/17-modr2.pdf) (Page 9). I attached a screenshot of page 9 here.

In particular, the slide says that **"if we center the columns of X, then the intercept estimate turns out to be $\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y}$."**

I don't see why this is true. Any explanation?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen why this is true for linear regression?